# DS.RESTSerializer async normalizePayload?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use `DS.RESTSerializer` to normalize a JSON response payload:

I need to call an async function from an external library (if you like the details, I need to change the context of a `JSON-LD` response, using the jsonld.js library). Unfortunately, it seems I cannot return a `Promise` from `normalizePayload`, so the only way I see is to rewrite the AJAX method in `DS.RESTAdapter`. Not so difficult, but I think this would be a good fit for `DS.RESTSerializer.normalizePayload`.

But I am very new to Ember.js, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have all of the information available for synchronous usage by the time you've returned the json from the find method.  It's easy enough to properly extend the find method (and not have to worry about it breaking in the future).

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  find: function(store, type, id) {
    var self;
    return this._super(store, type, id).then(function(json){
      return self.someAsyncMethodPromise(json);
    });
  },
  someAsyncMethodPromise: function(json){
    // return a promise here that results in the final json
  }
});
```

Comment: Much cleaner than rewriting the ajax method, thank you.